# structured query language error when running the code

Tags: sql, db2

When I try to run the below code; I received the following error.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_test
    (IN roger_value INT, dd VARCHAR(100), way_id INT)
LANGUAGE SQL MODIFIES SQL DATA
    INSERT INTO testall
    VALUES
        (000, roger_value, dd, 777, way_id);

CREATE TRIGGER test1
AFTER INSERT ON testall
FOR EACH ROW mode DB2SQL
UPDATE testall
SET     way_out = way_out + 1,
        way_in = way_in + 1;

CREATE TRIGGER test2
AFTER INSERT ON testall
FOR EACH ROW mode DB2SQL
DELETE FROM testfirst
WHERE (SELECT testfirst.roger_value FROM testfirst) = (SELECT testall.roger_value FROM testall);  


CALL proc_test(999, 'testvalue', 8888) ;


Status:
Failed
Error message
An error occurred in a triggered SQL statement in trigger "schema111.test2".  Information returned for the error includes SQLCODE "-811", SQLSTATE "21000" and message tokens "".. SQLCODE=-723, SQLSTATE=09000, DRIVER=4.27.25
```

I am not sure what is happening after trying many sites but still no answer. Can anyone help?

Comment: anyone could help?

Comment: [SQL0811N](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=messages-sql0750-sql0999): The result of a scalar fullselect, SELECT INTO statement, or VALUES INTO statement is more than one row. You get this error in trigger `test2`, if `testfirst` has more than 1 row. Each subselect returns more than 1 row in this case which is forbidden. Could you explain the strange logic of this trigger in words?

Comment: BTW, do you really want to update all rows in the `testall` table with the `test1` trigger upon inserting a new row into this table?

Comment: I am so sorry, I dont understand what are you trying to say. Which one do you mean?

Comment: Is there anyone could assist with this?

Comment: Look at the [test2 trigger problem](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=7893b5c374c13a13c132ff878ce9ea49) example. Do you understand the explanation?

Comment: thank you. But is there a way to access the testall table without the select within clauses?

Comment: You still haven't explained the desired `test2` trigger logic. Which rows do you want to delete from `testfirst` exactly?

Comment: the row that has the same value for roger_value in testfirst.

Comment: What I wanted to do is to after INSERT ON, it will trigger test1 and update the rows and then also trigger test2 which compare the roger_value for testfirst with testall and remove it.

Comment: my where should be something like testfirst .roger_value = testall. roger_value but I do not know how to access two tables with my code.

Answer (score 0):

If I divine your intention correctly, make the following changes:

1. Use the keyword `new` to refer to the row being inserted
2. Fix the syntax

Applying these points makes the delete:

```
DELETE FROM testfirst
WHERE roger_value = NEW.roger_value;
```

Comment: I wish to do something like where testfirst .roger_value = testall. roger_value

Comment: what is the NEW for?

Comment: @Learner91 read about it in [the documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-create-trigger).

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to delete all rows from `testfirst` having the same `ROGER_VALUE` value as in the inserted row into `testall`, then:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test2
AFTER INSERT ON testall
REFERENCING NEW AS N
FOR EACH ROW mode DB2SQL
DELETE FROM testfirst F
WHERE F.ROGER_VALUE = N.ROGER_VALUE
```

If the goal is to update some values in the inserted row only (and not in all table rows), then:

```
CREATE TRIGGER test1
BEFORE INSERT ON testall
REFERENCING NEW AS N
FOR EACH ROW mode DB2SQL
SET     way_out = N.way_out + 1,
        way_in = N.way_in + 1
```

Comment: Thank you but when I try that for delete- the first example, I get error 532

Comment: Why is not possible for testall.roger_value? Also what is the NEW for? –

Comment: I can see that the NEW is replace for testall but I dont understand why. We cant just use testall.roger_value, right?

Comment: [SQL0532N](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/sql0500-sql0749.html#sql0532n): A parent row cannot be deleted because the relationship constraint-name restricts the deletion. You have some another table referencing `testfirst` with its foreign key constraint. Study the [CREATE TRIGGER statement](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-create-trigger) link about the correlation names use. Additional useful link: [triggers](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=objects-triggers).